# Не показывается preview xml (ошибка timeout)

Tags: android, android-studio

При открытии сложного xml file в Android Studio preview вываливается с ошибкой timeout и не показывает preview соответственно.  Переустановка студии и очистка кэша не помогает. Что делать?